# AngularJS cannot see required field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to make sure the `name` input matches the pattern. AngularJS cannot see `name` and set required error although they are reside in one div. It's not rational to start declatation from `form` bacause it has a lot of divs without names. How to make `required` field visible to Angular?

```
<form ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl" action="" name="productForm" class="form-horizontal" id="addproductForm" role="form" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': productName.$invalid }">
        <label for="product_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">product name: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input id="product_name" name="productName" type="text" ng-model="testproductName" ng-pattern='/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/' required/>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ng-model` in your input attributes to makes angular observe it.
And your errors need to be attached to your form name.

See this :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>

  <form name="form">
    <input ng-model="test" name="myField" required>
    <span ng-show="form.myField.$error.required">Required</span>
  </form>
  
</div>
```